# HTM BeginCollectionItem returns only first item of collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, begincollectionitem

I have the following problem:

A collection of "Gifts" gets passed as a parameter to a view.
Each item inside this collection is a object from the Model class "Gift".
There are only two properties inside this class: name and price.
I put the class inside the controller for the sake of simplicity.

This is the action method:

```
// GET: Order/CreateGift
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateGift()
    {
        var initialData = new[]
        {
            new Gift{ Name = "Tricycle", Price = 69.95 },
            new Gift{ Name = "PS4 game", Price = 29.99 },
            new Gift{ Name = "Lazergun", Price = 49.99}
        };

        return View(initialData);
    }
```

On the view I can dynamically add new items to the collection, thanks to the BeginCollectionItem Html helper.

This is my View:

```html
@model IEnumerable<DemoWebShop.Controllers.Gift>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#addItem").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
            });
            return false;
        });

    }); // end document.ready function

</script>

<h2>Gift List</h2>
    What do you want for your birthday?

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div id="editorRows">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("GiftEditorRow", item);
            }
        </div>

        @Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })

        <input type="submit" value="Finished" />

        @*<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Aanmaken" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>*@

    </div>
}
```

This is the partial view called "GiftEditorRow" :

```html
@using HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem

@model DemoWebShop.Controllers.Gift


@{
 Layout = null;

}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="editorRow">

        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts"))
        {
            <label>Name: </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name);
            <label>Price: </label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price, new { size = 4 });
            <br />
        }
    </div>

}
```

Inside my controller I also have this actionmethod:

```
    public ViewResult BlankEditorRow()
    {
        return View("GiftEditorRow", new Gift());
    }
```

Only the First item that already existed inside the collection, gets passed to the HTTP Post method in my controller.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
The partial view "GiftEditorRow" still contains the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){.....}
```

If you remove this, it should work.

This is my partial view now:

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("gifts"))
{
    <label>Name: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Name);
    <label>Price: </label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Price, new { size = 4 });
    <br />
}
```

Now I get all items instead of just the first one.